# Is posible represent rectangular pulse in Matlab using vector?

Tags: matlab, plot, vector, representation, pulse

I have to represent this pulses in Matlab but only when i find a 0 in a vector

[image]

This is my code, i generate a vector with 10 numbers 0s and 1s but I am not able to program the representation of the pulse when a 0 appears in the vector.

```
L=10;
bits = rand(1,L) < 0.5; 


dom = [1:length(bits)];

for c = length(bits):-1:2
    if bits(c) ~= 1
        bits = [bits(1:c-1), bits(c-1:end)];
        dom = [dom(1:c),dom(c:end)];
    end

end
figure(2)
plot (dom,bits)
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure what the desired output is. Could you add a couple of examples? For each example, a given `bits` pattern input, and the desired final `bits` pattern. The design you are using, where the `bits` vector is changing inside the loop which is stepping through the selfsame vector is hard for my the understand. I would have built a separate array.

Comment: You're asking about pulses; however, you're only specifying a 10 element vector to represent the signal with the pulse in it.  Is there a specific frequency you need to be working with, or are you just trying to represent a pulse with an abstract signal of no specific frequency?  Also, your picture depicts 3 different signals.  Do you need code for all 3?  Also, if you need to represent the ramp in the last plot, you'll need to use something other than logicals (the result of the < 0.5 in your first assignment to bits).